# How can I prove this argument?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Using the follow theorem:

> Let $a$ and $b$ two positive integers numbers so $gcd(a,b) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \exists s,t \in \mathbb{Z} : sa+tb = 1$

I want to prove that if $a\mid bc \mbox{ and } gcd(a,c) = 1 \rightarrow a\mid b$

Using the definition of divisibility I arrived at: $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : ak = bc$. Using this and the theorem I isolate the c, I arrived in $ak = b\frac{1-sa}{t}$. But I can not get anywhere from there,I can not see a way to do it the way I'm thinking

Comment: Is $mdc$ also known as the greatest-common-divisor?

Comment: Did you mean to prove $a\mid bc \mbox{ and } mdc(a,c) = 1 \rightarrow a\mid \color{red}b$?

Answer (score 2):

You use the theorem to represent 1 in terms of a and c.  Then multiply both sides of the equation by b.  On the left, you see that a | ab (obviously), and you are given that a | bc.  See where this goes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Just not being able to establish the relationship between $a\mid ab \mbox{ and } a\mid bc$